# Appgyver Supersonic Drawer not showing up

Tags: css, steroids

I have tried to show a left drawer in a Steroids Supersonic example application. 
I don't have tabs, I use a root view.

I use the following code in the `structure.coffee` file (this is the only file I changed):

```
# Read more about app structure at http://docs.appgyver.com

module.exports =

  # See styling options for tabs and other native components in app/common/native-styles/ios.css or app/common/native-styles/android.css
    rootView:
     location: "example#getting-started"

  preloads: [
    {
      id: "learn-more"
      location: "example#learn-more"
    }
    {
      id: "using-the-scanner"
      location: "example#using-the-scanner"
    }
  ]

  drawers:
    left:
      id: "leftDrawer"
      location: "example#drawer"
      showOnAppLoad: false
     options:
      animation: "swingingDoor"

  initialView:
     id: "initialView"
     location: "example#initial-view"
```

Nothing shows up on the left side. If I change the `showOnAppLoad` to true, nothing is visible.

What else should I set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a *coffeescript* error: the creators of the framework were *so smart that the compilation depends on* ***indentation***. Great thinking...very constructive.

Comment: Almost a year later, I had the same problem and this answer saved me after like 2 hours of trying! I had the error `"supersonic.ui.drawers.open rejected: There are no drawers"` showing up in logs on Android and total freeze of the app withous error on iOS. The problem was that my teammate edited the _structure.coffee_ file to add tabs to the app, and when uncommenting the part he left 3 spaces in the indentation instead of 2. Always remember **indentation** in **coffee files** on Appgyver works by **PAIRS of spaces**.

Comment: @rAthur Glad it could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anybody visited this page looking for solution:

in `structure.coffee` file

```
  // the line below should be intended so it become part of array above it
  drawers:
    left:
      id: "leftDrawer"
      location: "home#drawer"
      ...etc
```